# Is there a way to get gcc to output raw binary?

Tags: linux, gcc, command-line, linker, x86

Is there a set of command-line options that will convince gcc to produce a flat binary file from a self-contained source file?  For example, suppose the contents of foo.c are

```
static int f(int x)
{
  int y = x*x;
  return y+2;
}
```

No external references, nothing to export to the linker. I'd like to get a small file with just the machine instructions for this function, without any other decoration. Sort of like a (DOS) .COM file except 32-bit protected mode.

Comment: Two fine answers submitted at the same time. I don't know which one to  give the check mark.

Comment: You can consider accepting a [more recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23502466/1483676) which directly answers your question (pure compiler/linker answer).

Comment: A `static` function with no callers in its translation unit will optimize away.  So remove the `static` before using the answers.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try this out:

```
$ gcc -c test.c     
$ objcopy -O binary -j .text test.o binfile
```

You can make sure it's correct with `objdump`:

```
$ objdump -d test.o 
test.o:     file format pe-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <_f>:
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   83 ec 04                sub    $0x4,%esp
   6:   8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   9:   0f af 45 08             imul   0x8(%ebp),%eax
   d:   89 45 fc                mov    %eax,-0x4(%ebp)
  10:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
  13:   83 c0 02                add    $0x2,%eax
  16:   c9                      leave  
  17:   c3                      ret
```

And compare it with the binary file:

```
$ hexdump -C binfile 
00000000  55 89 e5 83 ec 04 8b 45  08 0f af 45 08 89 45 fc  |U......E...E..E.|
00000010  8b 45 fc 83 c0 02 c9 c3                           |.E......|
00000018
```

Comment: I had to include `-j .text` as a parameter to `objcopy` to get the correct result.

Comment: Why? What happened when you didn't?

Comment: It copied the wrong (not .text) section from the .o file. Version: `GNU objcopy version 2.22.52.0.1-10.fc17 20120131`

Comment: Be careful with passing the result of `cc -c` directly to `objcopy` without an intermediate `ld`. If `cc` decides to emit any relocations, `ld` won't be around to process them, and the binary will be wrong. (The binary will have null bytes where there should be addresses or offsets.) `cc` might emit relocations even if the source file appears, as the question mentions, "self-contained."

Answer (score 28):

You can pass options to the linker directly with `-Wl,<linker option>`

The relevant documentation is copied below from the `man gcc`

> -Wl,option 
>   Pass option as an option to the linker. If option contains commas, it is split into multiple options at the commas. You can use
>   this syntax to pass an argument to the option. For example,
>   -Wl,-Map,output.map passes -Map output.map to the linker. When using the GNU linker, you can also get the same effect with
>   -Wl,-Map=output.map.

So when compiling with gcc if you pass `-Wl,--oformat=binary` you will generate a binary file instead of the elf format. Where `--oformat=binary` tells `ld` to generate a binary file.

This removes the need to `objcopy` separately.

Note that `--oformat=binary` can be expressed as `OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")` from within a [linker script](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Format-Commands.html#Format-Commands). If you want to deal with flat binaries, there's a big chance that you would benefit from high level of control that linker scripts provide.

Comment: Actually this answer is the only real valid answer here... I'd say that others are acceptable workarounds.

Comment: For future reference: the `--oformat=binary` solution seems to emit incorrect machine code in some cases *or* I'm not aware of something, but if you by any chance encounter some weird behavior of external symbols, then try `objcopy` solution.

Comment: I ran into [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63106614/why-did-ld-turn-my-5-lines-of-library-less-c-into-a-100mb-binary) of the output binary being way too big (padded with zeros) when using this method.

Answer (score 19):

You can use [`objcopy`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objcopy.1.html) to pull the text segment out of the .o file or the a.out file.

```
$ cat q.c
f() {}
$ cc -S -O q.c
$ cat q.s
        .file   "q.c"
        .text
.globl f
        .type   f, @function
f:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        popl    %ebp
        ret
        .size   f, .-f
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.3.3-5ubuntu4) 4.3.3"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
$ cc -c -O q.c
$ objcopy -O binary q.o q.bin
$ od -X q.bin
0000000 5de58955 000000c3
0000005
$ objdump -d q.o
q.o:     file format elf32-i386
Disassembly of section .text:
00000000 <f>:
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   5d                      pop    %ebp
   4:   c3                      ret
```

Comment: You seem to have lost the link.

Answer (score 10):

The other answers are definitely the way to go.  However, I had to specify additional command line arguments to objcopy in order for my output to be as expected.  Note that I am developing 32-bit code on a 64-bit machine, hence the `-m32` argument.  Also, I like intel assembly syntax better, so you'll see that in the arguments as well.

```
$ cat test.c
int main() { return 0; }
$ gcc -nostdinc -m32 -masm=intel -Wall -c test.c -o test.o
$ objdump --disassemble --disassembler-options intel test.o

test.o:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <main>:
   0:   55                      push   ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
   3:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
   8:   5d                      pop    ebp
   9:   c3                      ret
```

Ok, here's where I had to specify that I specifically only wanted the .text section:

```
$ objcopy --only-section=.text --output-target binary test.o test.bin
$ hexdump -C test.bin
00000000  55 89 e5 b8 00 00 00 00  5d c3   |U.......].|
0000000a
```

It took me about 2 hours of reading and trying different options before I figured this out.  Hopefully this saves someone else that time.