# How to generate plain binaries like nasm -f bin with the GNU GAS assembler?

Tags: assembly, nasm, gnu-assembler

I have some NASM files that generally have the structure:

```
        [BITS 64]
        [ORG 0x0000000000200000]

start:
        ...

        ret
```

I'm assembling them like so:

```
nasm -f bin abc.asm
```

I'd like to write some of these using GAS instead. Two questions:

- What directives should I use in GAS? I've found the '.org' directive but GAS doesn't seem to have a '.bits' directive.
- What should I pass to `gcc` or `as` to generate a plain binary file? I.e. what the `-f bin` option does with NASM.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what is the target platform for that code? The most common I've seen is to see 16-bit bare assembly for boot sectors, but this is not the case since you're in 64-bits.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> What directives should I use in GAS? I've found the '.org' directive but GAS doesn't seem to have a '.bits' directive.

The assembler defaults to 64--bit for me, you can use `--32` or `--64` to chose on the command line. Have a look at the manual for [as](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.17/as/index.html) to see how you can change the architecture inside the code if needed (e.g. `.code16` can be used to generate real mode code for a boot loader).

You most likely don't want to use the `.org` directive to specify where the code is located, but will probably want to use a link script or specify where the text and data segments are loaded on the command line. (`org 0x0000000000200000` results in a 2+ MB binary file).

> What should I pass to gcc or as to generate a plain binary file? I.e. what the -f bin option does with NASM.

```
$ cat test.S
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
        xor %rax, %rax
        mov test, %rax
        ret

test: .quad 0x1234567812345678


$ as --64 -o test.o test.S
$ ld -Ttext 200000 --oformat binary -o test.bin test.o
```

`$ objdump -D -b binary -m i386:x86-64 test.bin
test.bin:     file format binary
Disassembly of section .data:`

0000000000000000 <.data>:
   0:   48 31 c0                xor    %rax,%rax
   3:   48 8b 04 25 0c 00 20    mov    0x20000c,%rax
   a:   00 
   b:   c3                      retq
   c:   78 56                   js     0x64
   e:   34 12                   xor    $0x12,%al
  10:   78 56                   js     0x68
  12:   34 12                   xor    $0x12,%al

Comment: The original NASM files include a file which contains lines like: `xyz equ 0x0000000000100010`. They then are able to do `call xyz`. I tried to do the same in GAS but this doesn't seem to work. I.e. using `.set xyz , 0x0000000000100010` and later `call xyz` doesn't seem to do the trick. Any thoughts? Perhaps I should open a separate question.

Comment: What kind of jump do you want? I don't think an absolute 64-bit call is possible. For indirect call you need `call *xyz`.

Comment: When I disassemble the NASM code, it shows: `callq  0xfffffffffff00040` for `call xyz` where `xyz equ 0x0000000000100040`.

Comment: Thanks again by the way! The goal here is to generate binaries for [BareMetal](http://www.returninfinity.com/baremetal.html) OS using GAS. Very simple ones which don't reference system calls are now working. Now I'm trying to resolve the above equ/call issue to access the system calls.

Comment: Also, when I disassemble the (not working) GAS code, it shows `callq  *0x100040` for `call xyz` where `.set xyz , 0x0000000000100040`.

Comment: Try `.set xyz, $0x0000000000100040`, otherwise open a new question.

Answer (score 11):

**`objcopy -O binary`**

A good option is:

```
as -o test.o test.S
ld -Ttext 0x7C00 -o test.elf test.o
objcopy -O binary kernel.elf kernel.bin
```

The advantage over `ld --oformat binary` is that it is easier to use the symbols to debug via:

```
qemu-system-i386 -hda main.img -S -s &
gdb main.elf -ex 'target remote localhost:1234'
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32960272/895245

**Linker script**

`-Ttext` is fine for quick and dirty testing, but for serious work you should use a script instead to increase robustness.

Otherwise, `ld` will use a default script (`ld --verbose`) intended for userland application, which does not look like your application.

Without further information, the minimal script I can give is:

```
SECTIONS
{
    . = 2M;
    .text :
    {
        *(.*)
    }
}
```

And then use it with `-T`:

```
as --64 -o test.o test.S
ld -T linker.ld --oformat binary -o test.bin test.o
```

But you will likely want to modify that script based on your exact application.

See also: [Is there a way to get gcc to output raw binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647359/is-there-a-way-to-get-gcc-to-output-raw-binary)

I have a repository with working examples for some common use cases:

- [boot sectors](https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/d217b180be4220a0b4a453f31275d38e697a99e0/multiboot/hello-world/linker.ld)
- [multiboot interfacing with C](https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/d217b180be4220a0b4a453f31275d38e697a99e0/multiboot/hello-world/linker.ld)

Comment: why do some people religiously do gcc -o outfile infile or as -o outfile infile when the att convention uses first as input, second as output . I know flex/bison dont even work if you put input before output. Whats the reasoning behind this?

Comment: @Dmitry to follow the same convention as most other CLI tools: first optional arguments `-o val` and then positional ones. Especially relevant when using `-- -positional -with -leading hyphens`.