# Assembly of PIC 

Tags: assembly, pic

The address of `str` is stored the stack(can use `pop` to fetch it, and it's position independent):

```
.text
    str:
        .string "test\n"
```

But now the address of `str` is  not in the stack(can't use `pop` to fetch it, but `str(%rip)`(RIP relative addressing) is PIC):

```
.text
    str:
        .skip 64
```

This is what I found from my previous question,

but I don't understand how assembler decides address of `str` should be in the stack or not?

WHen should I use RIP-relative addressing ,or use `pop` to make it PIC?

**UPDATE**

This is working:

```
.text
    call start
    str:
        .string "test\n"
    start:
    movq    $1, %rax
    movq    $1, %rdi
    popq     %rsi
    movq    $5, %rdx
    syscall
    ret
```

But if I change `popq     %rsi` to `lea str(%rip),%rsi`,it wlll cause segmentation fault...

Comment: The assembler can't put anything on the stack, because the stack isn't created until runtime. Nothing is on the stack unless you put it there.

Comment: @Je Rog: In both cases `str` is located in the text segment along with the code for the functions - pop will not retrieve anything. Are you asking about the difference between absolute and relative addressing modes, because then [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode) has a decent discussion?

Comment: @user786653 , why this works if the address is not stored on stack? Pay attention to `popq %rsi`. http://pastebin.com/tZ81FvZK

Comment: Because *you* put the address on the stack with the `call` instruction. `call` pushes the address of the following instruction (in this case your string) onto the stack and jumps to the target address.

Comment: @user786653 ,but why it doesn't work if I replace `popq     %rsi` with `mov str(%rip),     %rsi`?Segmentation fault will happen...

Comment: Please edit your question with the complete code that's working and the code that's not working, but it looks like you want to do `lea str(%rip), %rsi` to load `%rsi` with the address of `str` rather than load a quad word from the first 8 bytes of `str` as that instruction does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be completely clear: the `CALL` instruction pushes the address of the instruction following it onto the stack and jumps to the target address. This means that

```
x: call start 
y:
```

is morally equivalent to (ignoring that we trash `%rax` here):

```
x: lea y(%rip), %rax
   push %rax
   jmp start 
y:
```

Conversely `RET` pops an address from the stack and jumps to it.

Now in your code you do `popq %rsi` and then later `ret` jumps back to whatever called you. If you *just* change the `popq` to `lea str(%rip), %rsi` to load `%rsi` with the address of `str` you still have the return value (address of `str`) on the stack! To fix your code simply manually pop the return value off the stack (`add $8, %rsp`) OR more sanely move `str` to after the function so you don't need the awkward call.

Updated with complete stand alone example:

```
# p.s
#
# Compile using:
# gcc -c -fPIC -o p.o p.s
# gcc -fPIC -nostdlib -o p -Wl,-estart p.o

.text
.global start # So we can use it as an entry point
start:
    movq $1, %rax #sys_write
    movq $1, %rdi
    lea str(%rip), %rsi
    movq $5, %rdx
    syscall

    mov $60, %rax #sys_exit
    mov $0, %rdi
    syscall

.data
str:
    .string "test\n"
```

Disassembling the code with `objdump -d p` reveals that the code is indeed position independent, even when using `.data`.

```
p:     file format elf64-x86-64
Disassembly of section .text:
000000000040010c <start>:
  40010c:   48 c7 c0 01 00 00 00    mov    $0x1,%rax
  400113:   48 c7 c7 01 00 00 00    mov    $0x1,%rdi
  40011a:   48 8d 35 1b 00 20 00    lea    0x20001b(%rip),%rsi        # 60013c <str>
  400121:   48 c7 c2 05 00 00 00    mov    $0x5,%rdx
  400128:   0f 05                   syscall 
  40012a:   48 c7 c0 3c 00 00 00    mov    $0x3c,%rax
  400131:   48 c7 c7 00 00 00 00    mov    $0x0,%rdi
  400138:   0f 05                   syscall
```

Comment: Is it true assembly with `.data xxx` will NEVER be PIC? And it's still causing segfault when run as `gcc -nostdlib file.s -ggdb -o x;./x`, what's the caller of `x` when built without stdlib?

Comment: @Je Rog: No you just have to remember to use RIP-relative addressing (and possibly `-fPIC` on the command line, depends on what you're trying to achieve). And yes the code will segfault if you just run it like that (but so would yours in the question), I was assuming you were still using the loader from your previous question. If you want it to work stand-alone you need to use sys_exit (60) to end the program, there is nothing to return to. (`mov $60, %rax` `mov $0,%rdi` `syscall`).

Comment: I just tried adding `.data` before `str`,and it's not working even if I compile with `-fPIC`..

Comment: Run it with the loader, run as stand-alone can't prove it's PIC,right? Theoratically it can't be PIC since text and data are stored in different(non-consecutive) positions ...

Comment: @Je Rog: The ELF format (or a.out on ancient platforms) handles that. If you have special requirements as you do you need a link script. You  have to be upfront with *all* of the requirements. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828631/plain-binaries-with-gnu-assembler/6829145#6829145) post. You *possibly*  want something like this: `ld --oformat binary -pie -e start -Ttext=0x0000 -Tdata=0x1000 -o p.bin p.o`

Comment: But it's actually not working if I add `.data` before `str`, I tested it in the loader;And it works if I remove `.data`.

Comment: Again, it's impossible to guess what you're doing/trying, you have to be extremely clear what you're trying to do/have tried. In this case, what *exactly* are you using with your loader (and what is the source code of it), how are you compiling and linking the different parts? Did you try my latest suggestion? If yes, what part isn't working, did you debug?

Comment: I'm running it this way: `gcc -c -fPIC write.S -o write.o;objcopy -O binary write.o write.bin;./loader write.bin`,the loader is the same as in the previous post..

Comment: So you didn't try what I suggested? Rather than use `objcopy` (which you haven't mentioned using before) try doing `ld .... -o write.bin write.o` with the `...` part copied from my previous answer.

Comment: I tried,but after that it can neither be run as stand-alone(`cannot execute binary file`) nor run by the loader(`Segmentation fault`)

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong. http://pastebin.com/PGZERsDR `make && ./p && ./run p.bin`. Open a new question WITH ALL THE AVAILABLE INFORMATION AND CODE if you're still having trouble. Perhaps someone else can explain things better for you...

Comment: Why do you specify `-Ttext=0x0000 -Tdata=0x100`? It seems this is making the address fixed,and not PIC .. And I tried `make run;./run p`,it reports `Segmentation fault`

Comment: That's where they will be located *in the file*. `p` is an ELF file with headers and so forth that you can't expect to be able to just jump to.