# Is it possible to produce a plain binary file only using GNU Assembler on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, assembly, abi

I wrote some assembly code for x86, and wanted to assemble it into plain binary file (not Mach-O) by just using Mac's default assembler (the 'as'). After several googlings and tries, I failed.

Though I know how to do it with NASM (using option: -f binary), I don't want to do so. Because my code was written in and I was used to AT&T syntax.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plain binaries with GNU assembler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828631/plain-binaries-with-gnu-assembler)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `objcopy` (which is part of binutils as is `as`) with `--output-target` set to `binary`.

```
as --64 test.s -o test.o
objcopy -O binary test.o test.bin
```

And to disassemble the output:

```
objdump -D -m i386:x86-64:intel -b binary test.bin
```

(Substitute `--32` and remove `x86-64:` for 32-bit versions)

Comment: I think this is not easy to do with Mac, since the binutils included in Xcode Developer Tools uses modified `as` and even has no `objdump` packed in.

Comment: Hmm, looks like you're right, sorry. Perhaps [Agner Fogs objconv](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#objconv) can help you until I figure something better out.

Comment: Thanks. It's a great tool, but it seems that it do not support the conversion between Mach-O and flat binary format according to its manual. Or am I missing something? Actually, after a little research I find there is no obvious way to do it with Mac's limited tools and I'll try out your first approach some day by building a cross-compile environment of GNU tool chain. At the current time, NASM looks like the most quick workaround to me.

Comment: You also need to use `ld` between `as` and `objcopy`. (See [this answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32594933/497934) for an example.) Without it, the binary will be missing relocations. For very small, simple assemblies that happen not to generate any relocations, things might appear to work regardless.