# How to use a string literal as an immediate operand (and move it to an address) in GNU assembler?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

I mean something that I write in NASM like this:

```
mov dword [0xA0BF17C], ' : )'
```

I have tried such a things in GNU assembler:

```
movd " : )", 0xB8000

movd $" : )", 0xB8000

movd ' : )', 0xB8000

movd " : )", $0xB8000
```

But... They all caused this error:

```
Error: unbalanced parenthesis in operand 1.
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible like this in the GNU assembler.  Have you checked the manual?

Comment: It wasn't written how to do it there, but that doesn't mean you can't do it.

Comment: So basically, the GNU assembler does not support using string literals as integer constants.  One solution is to manually look up the ASCII codes of these characters and form an integer literal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GAS only supports single-character literals as numbers.  UTF-8 multi-byte single character is ok, but *not* multiple separate characters.  You could do `movb  $' ', 0xB8000`, but you don't want to use 4 instructions for 4 bytes.

You have two real options: shift together single-character literals into a number, or write it out in hex.  (Both ways taking into account that x86 is little-endian)

```
# NASM   mov eax, "abcd"
movl  $'a' + ('b'<<8) + ('c'<<16) + ('d'<<24),  0xB8000
movl  $0x64636261,  0xB8000         # or manual ASCII -> hex, little-endian
```

The shift/add trick works with any arbitrary bytes; you could maybe even make a `#define` CPP macro to do it (taking 4 args).

With an EAX destination instead of memory (to simplify the machine code), disassembled back into GAS Intel syntax (`objdump -drwC -Mintel`), we can see they both assembled identically (with `as --32`):

```
   0:   b8 61 62 63 64          mov    eax,0x64636261
   5:   b8 61 62 63 64          mov    eax,0x64636261
```

Or with your memory destination.  Again, 32-bit mode since this would #GP fault in real mode from exceeding the 64k DS segment limit with that 0xb8000 offset.
Also notice that the immediate bytes in the machine code are in the same order that will be stored as data to the memory destination.  (And they match source order if you were using NASM `mov dst, "abcd"`.

```
a:   c7 05 00 80 0b 00 61 62 63 64   mov    DWORD PTR ds:0xb8000,0x64636261
```

---

Unlike NASM, **GAS doesn't support multi-character character literals as numeric constants.**  It so doesn't support them that they even confuse GAS's parser<sup>1</sup>!  GAS was mostly designed for assembling compiler output, and compilers don't need this.

GAS only supports (double) quoted strings of multiple characters as args to `.ascii` / `.asciz` / `.string8/16/32`, not to `.byte` (unlike NASM `db`) or as an immediate operand for an instruction.

**If it was supported, the x86 AT&T syntax would be `movl $' : )', 0xB8000`**.
Not `movd`, and an immediate operand always needs a `$`.

See [When using the MOV mnemonic to load/copy a string to a memory register in MASM, are the characters stored in reverse order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57427904/when-using-the-mov-mnemonic-to-load-copy-a-string-to-a-memory-register-in-masm/57436181#57436181) for NASM vs. MASM vs. GAS with multi-character literals.  Only NASM works intuitively.

---

**Double quotes don't work either**: `mov $"foo", %eax` assembles, but it assembles the same as `mov $foo, %eax` - putting the address of the symbol `foo` into a register.  See [relocation R_X86_64_8 against undefined symbol `ELF' can not be used when making a PIE object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62258430/relocation-r-x86-64-8-against-undefined-symbol-elf-can-not-be-used-when-making) for an example of that.

---

**Footnote 1:**  Hence errors like "unbalanced parenthesis" instead of something sensible like "character literal contains multiple characters".

```
mov $'abcd', %eax
```

is another example of totally confusing the parser.  It sees the `b` as a backward symbol reference for local labels, like `jmp 1b` to reference a `1:` label in the backwards direction.  But the label number it's looking for here is 97, the ASCII value of `'a'`.  This is totally bonkers

```
foo.s: Assembler messages:
foo.s:4: Error: backward ref to unknown label "97:"
foo.s:4: Error: junk `cd44%eax' after expression
foo.s:4: Error: number of operands mismatch for `mov'
```

All of this was tested with `as --version` = *GNU assembler (GNU Binutils) 2.34*.

Comment: Related: [How are dw and dd different from db directives for strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38860174) for NASM, [When using the MOV mnemonic to load/copy a string to a memory register in MASM, are the characters stored in reverse order?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57436181) for MASM