# How to use GNU Assembler (GAS) to create a hand-written ELF File from the corresponding .s file

Tags: assembly, x86-64, ld, elf, gnu-assembler

## Introduction

I am trying to learn about `ELF` Files, and also experiment with them a little bit. Currently, I am following the tutorial [here](https://www.muppetlabs.com/%7Ebreadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html), which is about creating a tiny 32-bit `ELF` file that just exits with code 42. This tutorial uses `NASM` and `ld` to create the `ELF` files. However, I would like to use the `GNU Assembler (GAS)` to create a 64-bit `ELF` file (and not 32-bit), as I am somewhat familiar with it (but not an expert using it!)

I am currently stuck at the part of the tutorial where they start making `ELF` files from scratch - which involves writing `ELF` header and the program headers. Since 32-bit and 64-bit `ELF` files differ slightly (for example, in terms of ELF header size), my version of the `.s` file is below:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
ehdr:
        .byte 0x7F
        .byte 0x45 # E
        .byte 0x4c # L
        .byte 0x46 # F
        .byte 0x02 # 64 bit ; CLASS
        .byte 0x01 # lsb ; DATA
        .byte 0x01 # ; VERSION
        .byte 0x00 # None/Sytem V ; OS ABI
        .8byte 0x0 # ABI VERSION + PADDING

        .2byte 0x02 # ET_EXEC ; E_TYPE
        .2byte 0x3E # AMD64 ; E_MACHINE
        .4byte 0x01 # 1 ; E_VERSION
        .8byte _start # ; E_ENTRY
        .8byte phdr - ehdr # offset into program header ; E_PHOFF
        .8byte 0x00 # offset into section header ; E_SHOFF
        .4byte 0x00 # flag ; E_FLAGS
        .2byte ehdrsize # ELF header size ; E_EHSIZE
        .2byte phdrsize # Program header size ; E_PHSIZE
        .2byte 0x01 # Number of program headers ; E_PHNUM
        .2byte 0x00 # Section header size ; E_SHENTSIZE
        .2byte 0x00 # Number of section headers ; E_SHNUM
        .2byte 0x00 # Section header string table index ; E_SHSTRNDX

DECLARE_ELF_HEADER_SIZE:
.set ehdrsize,  DECLARE_ELF_HEADER_SIZE - ehdr

phdr:
        .4byte 0x01 # PT_LOAD ; P_TYPE
        .4byte 0x00 # located at offset 0??? ; P_OFFSET
        .8byte ehdr # ; P_VADDR
        .8byte ehdr # ; P_PADDR
        .8byte filesize # ; P_FILESIZE
        .8byte filesize # ; P_MEMSZ
        .8byte 5 # R-X ; P_FLAGS
        .8byte 0x1000 # P_ALIGN

DECLARE_PHEADER_SIZE:
.set phdrsize, DECLARE_PHEADER_SIZE - phdr

_start:
        mov eax, 60
        mov edi, 42
        syscall

DECLARE_FILE_SIZE:
.set filesize, DECLARE_FILE_SIZE - ehdr
```

More on ELF file headers can be found by looking at the corresponding source code [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/elf.h). **As I am still learning about `ELF` files, the above code might be incorrect (please let me know in case you find any fault!)**

## Problem

Assuming the above code is correct, I would like to convert the above `.s` file into an `ELF` file. For this, the tutorial uses the command:

```
$ nasm -f bin -o a.out tiny.asm
```

However, I am unable to find out what corresponding command I should use with GAS to create the corresponding `ELF` file, and that is the problem that I am facing.

## What I Have Tried...

I have tried various approaches. I will list them below:

1. There is a similar question on SO, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828631/how-to-generate-plain-binaries-like-nasm-f-bin-with-the-gnu-gas-assembler?noredirect=1&lq=1). This approach uses the following 2 commands to get the corresponding ELF file:

```
$ as --64 -o test.o test.s 
$ ld -Ttext 200000 --oformat binary -o test.bin test.o
```

Running the same commands for the `.s` file I have written, I do get an ELF file, **along with the following warning**:

```
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000200000
```

**Running the ELF file generated gets a segmentation fault, and exits with code 139.** The `ELF` header for the generated file is below (obtained by running `readelf -h <output ELF file>`):

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x200078
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          0 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         1
  Size of section headers:           0 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         0
  Section header string table index: 0
readelf: Error: the segment's file size is larger than its memory size
```

I believe the segmentation fault is happening because the `Entry Point address` is most likely incorrect (that was also hinted by `ld` in the error message).

2. In this approach, I modified the commands:

```
$ as --64 -o test.o test.s 
$ ld -Ttext 200000 --oformat binary -o test.bin test.o
```

to

```
$ as --64 -o test.o test.s (same as before) 
$ ld -nmagic -s test.o (changed)
```

This also creates an ELF file, **but again with the following warning**:

```
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000400078
```

**And this again hints that we are going to get a segmentation fault, which is indeed the case with the new `ELF` file.** The ELF header for this file is:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x400078
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          0 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         1
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         0
  Section header string table index: 0
```

No luck!

3. From the warnings given by `ld`, it looks like we might want to add `.global _start` in our `.s` file. Below is the new `.s` file that contains this line as well:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.global _start   # Added here
ehdr:
        .byte 0x7F
        .byte 0x45 # E
        .byte 0x4c # L
        .byte 0x46 # F
        .byte 0x02 # 64 bit ; CLASS
        .byte 0x01 # lsb ; DATA
        .byte 0x01 # ; VERSION
        .byte 0x00 # None/Sytem V ; OS ABI
        .8byte 0x0 # ABI VERSION + PADDING

        .2byte 0x02 # ET_EXEC ; E_TYPE
        .2byte 0x3E # AMD64 ; E_MACHINE
        .4byte 0x01 # 1 ; E_VERSION
        .8byte _start # ; E_ENTRY
        .8byte phdr - ehdr # offset into program header ; E_PHOFF
        .8byte 0x00 # offset into section header ; E_SHOFF
        .4byte 0x00 # flag ; E_FLAGS
        .2byte ehdrsize # ELF header size ; E_EHSIZE
        .2byte phdrsize # Program header size ; E_PHSIZE
        .2byte 0x01 # Number of program headers ; E_PHNUM
        .2byte 0x00 # Section header size ; E_SHENTSIZE
        .2byte 0x00 # Number of section headers ; E_SHNUM
        .2byte 0x00 # Section header string table index ; E_SHSTRNDX

DECLARE_ELF_HEADER_SIZE:
.set ehdrsize,  DECLARE_ELF_HEADER_SIZE - ehdr

phdr:
        .4byte 0x01 # PT_LOAD ; P_TYPE
        .4byte 0x00 # located at offset 0??? ; P_OFFSET
        .8byte ehdr # ; P_VADDR
        .8byte ehdr # ; P_PADDR
        .8byte filesize # ; P_FILESIZE
        .8byte filesize # ; P_MEMSZ
        .8byte 5 # R-X ; P_FLAGS
        .8byte 0x1000 # P_ALIGN

DECLARE_PHEADER_SIZE:
.set phdrsize, DECLARE_PHEADER_SIZE - phdr

_start:
        mov eax, 60
        mov edi, 42
        syscall

DECLARE_FILE_SIZE:
.set filesize, DECLARE_FILE_SIZE - ehdr
```

Again, we create the ELF file for the above code using:

```
$ as --64 -o test.o test.s 
$ ld -nmagic -s test.o
```

**This time, we don't get any errors and the ELF file does what it is supposed to do (that is, exits with code 42).** The ELF header for this file is:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x4000f0
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          0 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         1
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         0
  Section header string table index: 0
```

Problem solved, eh?

**Unfortunately, I don't think so.** Delving a bit deeper into the binary reveals that it **does not** use the hand-written `ELF` header that we had written in the `.s` file:

```
gef➤  search-pattern 'ELF'
[+] Searching 'ELF' in memory
[+] In '/home/VM/Desktop/Experiments/ELF/a.out'(0x400000-0x401000), permission=r-x
  0x400001 - 0x400004  →   "ELF[...]"
  0x400079 - 0x40007c  →   "ELF[...]"
```

Oops, it looks like `ld` (or `as`, I am not sure!) created their own `ELF` header (as is evident from the fact that there are 2 locations containing the string `ELF`. From what I understand, the `ELF` string at `0x400001` is the one that was contributed by `ld` (or `as`), and the one at `0x400079` was what I had included in the `.s` file.

However, this defeats the very own purpose of writing an ELF file from scratch, including the `ELF` header and program headers! I am also sure this problem is present in approaches 1 and 2 that I listed before, but since they anyway exited with a segmentation fault, I did not highlight this issue in those approaches.

Now, I am out of ideas on what to do, so I would highly appreciate any help for getting the `ELF` file correctly built!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you need an example, I have uploaded a test program doing this as [selbstverwirklichung.tar.xz](http://fuz.su/~fuz/src/selbstverwirklichung.tar.xz) on my website.  The program increments a counter and then dumps its new memory image onto disk, so each time you run it, you get a higher counter than before.  The comments are partially in German, but perhaps translation software can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message about the `_start` is a red herring. That is normally used to fill in the entry point but since you do that manually and are not using the linker to emit the ELF header it's irrelevant. You got the phdr wrong. In particular, the `p_offset` should be 8 bytes, the `p_flags` should be 4 bytes and placed as the second field. The fixed version is:

```
    .4byte 0x01 # PT_LOAD ; P_TYPE
    .4byte 5 # R-X ; P_FLAGS
    .8byte 0 # located at offset 0??? ; P_OFFSET
    .8byte ehdr # ; P_VADDR
    .8byte ehdr # ; P_PADDR
    .8byte filesize # ; P_FILESIZE
    .8byte filesize # ; P_MEMSZ
    .8byte 0x1000 # P_ALIGN
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I totally overlooked that while following the tutorial! However, If I include these changes and try to build the ELF file using `as --64 -o test.o test.s ; ld -Ttext 200000 --oformat binary -o test.bin test.o`, I still get a segmentation fault

Comment: Works on my machine. Does `readelf` look good?

Comment: Oh my bad! I ran the wrong ELF, it works! Great answer :)