# Triple fault on stack in C code

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, stack, osdev

I am writing a toy kernel for learning purposes, and I am having a bit of trouble with it. I have made a simple bootloader that loads a segment from a floppy disk (which is written in 32 bit code), then the bootloader enables the A20 gate and turns on protected mode. I can jump to the 32 bit code fine if I write it in assembler, but if I write it in C, I get a triple fault. When I disassemble the C code I can see that the first two instructions involve setting up a new stack frame. This is the key difference between the working ASM code and the failing C code.
I am using NASM v2.10.05 for the ASM code, and GCC from the DJGPP 4.72 collection for the C code.

This is the bootloader code:

```
org 7c00h
BITS 16

entry:
mov [drive], dl         ;Save the current drive


cli
mov ax,cs               ; Setup segment registers
mov ds,ax               ; Make DS correct
mov ss,ax               ; Make SS correct        

mov bp,0fffeh
mov sp,0fffeh           ;Setup a temporary stack
sti

;Set video mode to text
;===================
mov ah, 0
mov al, 3
int 10h
;===================

;Set current page to 0
;==================
mov ah, 5
mov al, 0
int 10h
;==================

;Load the sector
;=============
call load_image
;=============

;Clear interrupts
;=============
cli
;=============

;Disable NMIs
;============
in ax, 70h
and ax, 80h ;Set the high bit to 1
out 70h, ax
;============

;Enable A20:
;===========
mov ax, 02401h
int 15h
;===========

;Load the GDT
;===========
lgdt [gdt_pointer]
;===========

;Clear interrupts
;=============
cli
;=============

;Enter protected mode
;==================
mov eax, cr0
or eax, 1       ;Set the low bit to 1
mov cr0, eax
;==================

jmp 08h:clear_pipe  ;Far jump to clear the instruction queue


;======================================================
load_image:
reset_drive:
    mov ah, 00h
    ; DL contains *this* drive, given to us by the BIOS
    int 13h
    jc reset_drive

read_sectors:
    mov ah, 02h
    mov al, 01h
    mov ch, 00h
    mov cl, 02h
    mov dh, 00h
    ; DL contains *this* drive, given to us by the BIOS

    mov bx, 7E0h
    mov es, bx
    mov bx, 0

    int 13h
    jc read_sectors

ret
;======================================================

BITS 32 ;Protected mode now!
clear_pipe:

mov ax, 10h             ; Save data segment identifier
mov ds, ax              ; Move a valid data segment into the data segment register
mov es, ax
mov fs, ax
mov gs, ax
mov ss, ax              ; Move a valid data segment into the stack segment register
mov esp, 90000h        ; Move the stack pointer to 90000h
mov ebp, esp

jmp 08h:7E00h           ;Jump to the kernel proper

;===============================================
;========== GLOBAL DESCRIPTOR TABLE ==========
;===============================================

gdt:                    ; Address for the GDT

gdt_null:               ; Null Segment
    dd 0
    dd 0

gdt_code:               ; Code segment, read/execute, nonconforming
    dw 0FFFFh       ;   LIMIT, low 16 bits
    dw 0            ;   BASE, low 16 bits           
    db 0            ;   BASE, middle 8 bits
    db 10011010b    ;   ACCESS byte
    db 11001111b    ;   GRANULARITY byte
    db 0            ;   BASE, low 8 bits

gdt_data:               ; Data segment, read/write, expand down
    dw 0FFFFh
    dw 0
    db 0
    db 10010010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0

gdt_end:                ; Used to calculate the size of the GDT



gdt_pointer:                       ; The GDT descriptor
    dw gdt_end - gdt - 1    ; Limit (size)
    dd gdt                  ; Address of the GDT
;===============================================
;===============================================

drive: db 00    ;A byte to store the current drive in
times 510-($-$$) db 00
db 055h
db 0AAh
```

And this is the kernel code:

```
void main()
{
    asm("mov byte ptr [0x8000], 'T'");
    asm("mov byte ptr [0x8001], 'e'");
    asm("mov byte ptr [0x8002], 's'");
    asm("mov byte ptr [0x8003], 't'");
}
```

The kernel simply inserts those four bytes into memory, which I can check as I am running the code in a VMPlayer virtual machine. If the bytes appear, then I know the code is working. If I write code in ASM that looks like this, then the program works:

```
org 7E00h
BITS 32

main:
mov byte [8000h], 'T'
mov byte [8001h], 'e'
mov byte [8002h], 's'
mov byte [8003h], 't'

hang:
    jmp hang
```

The only differences are therefore the two stack operations I found in the disassembled C code, which are these:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
```

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated. I figure I am missing something relatively minor, but crucial, here, as I know this sort of thing is possible to do.

Comment: Are you sure you're jumping to the kernel? It looks like you're jumping to 0x08:0x7E00, and C doesn't necessarily put the main function at the top of the ELF or PE file that is spat out by the compiler (in fact, it never does).

Comment: You need to show us how you compile your C code.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention this bit. I am using the following commands:
`nasm -f bin bootloader.asm -o bootloader.bin`

`gcc -nostdinc -s -masm=intel -Wall -c kernel.c -o kernel.o`

`strip --strip-all kernel.o`
Then I did this to check the disassembled code:

`objdump --disassemble --disassembler-options intel kernel.o`

I am using the strip function which I found here on stackoverflow while researching how to use GCC, I find that it halves the binary down from ~600 bytes (too big for one sector) to ~340 or so.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you try to access the stack in your asm code? Are you sure you have RAM to use at the stack address of 90000h?

Comment: The VM has 256 meg of RAM. If I access the stack in assembly code (ie replacing the C binary with an assembly one) by adding a `push eax` then the code executes perfectly, and the values `Test` appear as expected in memory. However, if I get the disassembled C code, then assemble it in NASM, it still triple faults the computer. I had to change the disassembled code slightly so NASM would accept it: I changed all the `mov byte ptr ds:0x8000, 0x54` type lines to `mov byte [ds:0x8000], 0x54` instead. The fact that the disassembled C triple faults, but the plain ASM doesn't confuses me.

Comment: But the only difference between your disassembled code otherwise is the function prolog? Have you tried adding this to your asm file and seeing if this triple faults?

Comment: The other difference is at the end removing the `ret` and replacing it with a `jmp $`, as I forgot to add a `for(;;);` to the C code. Adding a `for(;;);` to the C code still triple faults, so that is unrelated. However, when I then prepend the disassembled C with `org 7E00h` and `BITS 32` and `main:` and reassemble with NASM, it all works correctly. I therefore conclude one of these two possibilities is the culprit:
GCC is compiling the C such that it expects it is at a location other than 7E00, OR
The extra information inside the compiled C code before the actual instructions is faulting

Comment: So therefore I need to find out how to add an ORG statement to C and also how to strip the file down so it is more like what NASM outputs.

Comment: I was thinking it might be the `ret` instruction trying to pop the return address off the stack (which won't be present as you `jmp`ed there - but when you compile the C code with an infinite loop and just allow to run (so it won't ever get to the ret instruction) it still triple-faults? It certainly sounds like there's something going on what gcc is compiling - are you able to post the disassembly which triple faults?

Comment: Here is the objdump of the GCC code. However I think that my problem is not in the code itself, but in the fact that as SecurityMatt said, the first bytes in the file are not code at all. I believe I need to use the LD linker as ring0 linked to. I'll have to use Pastebin here as the disassembly won't fit into this comment.
http://pastebin.com/iCdeNpUt

Comment: I followed the instructions in Michael's link, extracted the .text section to a binary file, and now I've got some bootable C code. So it looks like the problem wasn't the stack at all, but the extra information inside the C file. I was barking up the wrong tree with the stack! Thanks to everyone for your suggestions here, I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the technique here:

[Is there a way to get gcc to output raw binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647359/is-there-a-way-to-get-gcc-to-output-raw-binary)

to produce a flat binary of the .text section from your object file.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try moving the address of your protected mode stack to something else - say 0x80000 - which (according to this: http://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_(x86)) is RAM which is guaranteed free for use (as opposed to the address you currently use - 0x90000 - which apparently may not be present - depending a bit on what you're using as a testing environment).

Comment: Sorry - just saw your latest comment - obviously this is not the case if you can get the stack working correctly using non-C code.

Comment: Going back to my original code and only changing the stack pointer to 0x7FFF (ie making no other changes) still triple faults.
EDIT: Looks like we crossed posts there, never mind...