# Shellcode and binary files

Tags: c, shellcode

The below code is expecting a binary file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define bufsz 100

const char msg[] = "Usage: %s <shellcode file>\n";

static char buffer1[bufsz];
static char buffer2[bufsz];

void usage(char *self) {
    printf(msg, self);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp;
    void (*funcptr)();

    if (argc != 2)
        usage(argv[0]);

    if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb")) == NULL ) {
        printf("fail to open file: %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    };

    fgets(buffer1, bufsz, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    strcpy(buffer2, buffer1);

    if (strlen(buffer2) >= 40)
        printf("your shellcode is too long! \n");

    if (strlen(buffer2) < 30)
        printf("your shellcode is less than 30 bytes!\n");

    if (strstr(buffer2, "/bin/sh"))
        printf("Malicious code detected!\n");

    funcptr = (void *) buffer2;
    (*funcptr)(); /* execute your shell code */

    return 0;
}
```

Therefore, I created the below `shellfile.c` that contains 19 bytes to test the above app

```
int main(){
    /* push trick */
    __asm__("push $0;\n\
             push $2;\n\
             movl %esp, %ebx;\n\
             xorl %ecx, %ecx;\n\
             mov  $162, %al;\n\
             int  $0x80;\n\
             xorl %ebx, %ebx;\n\
             leal 0x1(%ebx), %eax;\n\
             int  $0x80;\n\               
             ");
    return 0;
    }
```

Compiled it, but the code is retrieving the below error:

```
gcc -o codetest -g -ggdb codetest.c
./runshell testcode
your shellcode is less than 30 bytes!
Illegal Instruction
```

Where is the issue exactly?

Comment: I'm curious -- what commands did you use to compile `shellfile.c`?

Comment: gcc -o shellfile -g -ggdb shellfile.c

Comment: That will be your next problem. `shellfile` will be an ELF file, not merely a stream of x86 instructions.

Comment: do you mean I have to extract the opcodes from the shellfile.c ?

Comment: No, that isn't what I mean.

Comment: After you fix the `fgets()`, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647359/is-there-a-way-to-get-gcc-to-output-raw-binary

Comment: could you please explain , what kind of file the program is expecting ?

Comment: You should break this down to smaller steps. Try simply running bytecode from a character array first, then add reading it from file and executing that. And use a debugger to analyse what's happening.

Comment: Are you sure the OS allow execution from the stack ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirements for your shellcode are :

- Length between 31 and 40
- No zero byte (`\x00`) or `strlen` will fail
- No '\n' byte (`\x0A`) or `fgets` will fail
- No "/bin/sh" substring

Your first instruction is `push $0` so the two first bytes of your shellcode is `\x6A\x00`.
The size of the buffer is `1` (`strlen` stops after a null byte).
That's why you have the error `your shellcode is less than 30 bytes!`.

Consider this shellcode, which is equivalent to yours, except `push $1` to avoid null byte :

```
6A01          push $1              ;to avoid null byte
6A02          push $2
89E3          movl %esp, %ebx      ;ebx now points on top of stack
31C9          xorl %ecx, %ecx      ;ecx=0
B0A2          mov  $162, %al       ;eax=162
CD80          int  $0x80           ;call sys_nanosleep because eax=162 with arguments ebx and ecx (ebx={1,2} and ecx=NULL)
31DB          xorl %ebx, %ebx      ;ebx=0
678D4301      leal 0x1(%ebx), %eax ;eax=1
CD80          int $0x80            ;call sys_exit because eax=1, with code 0 (ebx value)
```

Basically, this shellcode waits 2 seconds (and 1 nanosecond) and exits.
`int 0x80` is a system call depending of `eax` value, [more information here](http://www.shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/syscalls.html)

You still have a problem, the length of this shellcode is 20 bytes.
You just have to add eleven `NOP`'s (`0x90`) at the beginning (or at the end) to fill the requirement.

Try this :

```
echo -e '\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x6A\x01\x6A\x02\x89\xE3\x31\xC9\xB0\xA2\xCD\x80\x31\xDB\x67\x8D\x43\x01\xCD\x80' > shellcode.bin
./runshell shellcode.bin
```

If the program waits 2 seconds and successfully exits (with code 0), then the shellcode was executed.

If necessary, I can explain you how to code a shellcode which permits to get the rights of `runshell` program which is often the goal of this kind of exercice (and obviously the case here with the test on `"/bin/sh"`).

Comment: @moooeeeep `if (strlen(buffer2) >= 40)` and `if (strlen(buffer2) < 30)`

Comment: @moooeeeep, warnings, not notifications. These conditions validate the shellcode.

Answer (score 0):

```
fgets(buffer1, bufsz, fp);
...
if (strlen(buffer2)<30) 
    printf("your shellcode is less than 30 bytes!\n");
```

`fgets` is only valid for `\n`-delimited lines in a text file. `strlen` is only valid for zero-terminated character strings. Neither is appropriate for this use.

Try `fread()` instead.

Comment: I think he cannot modify this code, I guess it's an exercice to create a shellcode that satisfy the conditions of the code.

Comment: @Michael even when he manages to put the correct bytecode into the buffer this attempt will segfault when he tries to execute it.

Comment: @moooeeeep, yes because the file do not contains only the bytecode stream.