# Is it possible to assemble and run raw CPU instructions using `as`?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

There are a couple of related questions here.
Consider a program consisting only of the following two instructions

```
movq 1, %rax
cpuid
```

If I throw this into a file called `Foo.asm`, and run `as Foo.asm`, where `as` is the portable GNU assembler, I will get a file called `a.out`, of size 665 bytes on my system.

If I then `chmod 700 a.out` and try `./a.out`, I will get an error saying `cannot execute binary file`.

1. Why is the file so large, if I am merely trying to translate two `asm` instructions into binary?
2. Why can the binary not be executed? I am providing valid instructions, so I would expect the CPU to be able to execute them.
3. How can I get exactly the binary opcodes for the `asm` instructions in my input file, instead of a bunch of extra stuff?
4. Once I have the answer to 3, how can I get my processor to execute them? (Assuming that I am not running privileged instructions.)

Comment: Read [Linux Assembly HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/). In practice, better to embed `asm` statements in C code using [extended asm](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html)

Comment: You could avoid all overhead if you stopped using an operating system. However, then you wouldn't be able to use `as`.

Comment: Wow. I never knew that the files got so large (~20 to 665 bytes!)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. **Why is the file so large, if I am merely trying to translate two asm instructions into binary?**

   Because the assembler creates a [`relocatable object file`](http://downloads.openwatcom.org/ftp/devel/docs/elf-64-gen.pdf) which includes additional information, like *memory Sections* and *Symbol tables*.
2. **Why can the binary not be executed?**

   Because it is an (relocatable) `object file`, not a `loadable file`. You need to link it in order to make it executable so that it can be loaded by the operating system:

   ```
   $ ld  -o Foo a.out
   ```

   You also need to give the linker a hint about where your program starts, by specifying the `_start` symbol.

   But then, still, the `Foo` executable is larger than you might expect since it still contains additional information (e.g. the `elf header`) required by the operating system to actually launch the program.

   Also, if you launch the executable now, it will result in a `segmentation fault`, since you are loading the contents of `address` 1, which is not mapped into your address space, into `rax`. Still, if you fix this, the program will run into undefined code at the end - you need to make sure to gracefully exit the program through a `syscall`.

   A minimal running example (assumed x86_64 architecture) would look like

   ```
   .globl  _start
   _start:
       movq $1, %rax
       cpuid

       mov     $60, %rax       # System-call "sys_exit"
       mov     $0, %rdi        # exit code 0
       syscall
   ```
3. **How can I get exactly the binary opcodes for the asm instructions in my input file, instead of a bunch of extra stuff?**

   - [You can use `objcopy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647359/is-there-a-way-to-get-gcc-to-output-raw-binary) to generate a raw *binary image* from an *object file*:

     ```
     $ objcopy -O binary a.out Foo.bin
     ```

     Then, `Foo.bin` will **only** contain the instruction opcodes.
   - [nasm](http://www.nasm.us/) has a `-f bin` option which creates a binary-only representation of your assembly code. I used this to implement a [bare boot loader for VirtualBox](https://github.com/afester/CodeSamples/tree/master/Asm/MiniBoot) (warning: undocumented, protoype only!) to directly launch binary code inside a VirtualBox image without operating system.
4. **Once I have the answer to 3, how can I get my processor to execute them?**

   You will not be able to directly execute the raw *binary file* under Linux. You will need to write your own loader for that or not use an operating system at all. For an example, see my bare boot loader link above - this writes the opcodes into the boot loader of a VirtualBox disc image, so that the instructions are getting executed when launching the VirtualBox machine.

Comment: Ack with all, though on the nitpicker side, the `segmentation fault` for the code given above will _actually_ happen because `movq 1, %rax` tries to load an eight-byte value from address `0x1`, which is ... not mapped to anything, invalid. The person asking the question probably meant `movq $1, %rax` (at which point the remark would be ... `mov $1, %eax` is sufficient because that clears the upper 32bits as well). Disgressing ;-)

Comment: You might like this tutorial from Brian Raiter, although it uses Nasm rather than as. http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.

Comment: @FrankKotler Good reading! (actually, the link is http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html)

Answer (score 2):

The old MS-DOS COM file format does not include a header. It really only contains the binary executable code. The code size can, however, not exceed 64kb. I don't know whether Linux can execute these.

Answer (score 2):

You can write the opcodes into a file using a hexeditor. Then you just need to surround it with an elf header that Linux knows how to execute it.

Here's an example:

`hexedit myfile.bin`

Now just write your opcodes inside the file using the hexeditor.

After that you need to add the elf header. You could do this by hand and write the elf header into your .bin file, but that a bit tricky. Easiest method is to use a few commands (In this example for 64 bit).

1. `objcopy --input-target=binary --output-target=elf64-x86-64 myfile.bin myfile.o`
2. `ld -o myfile myfile.o -T binary.ld`

You will also need a linker script. I called this for example `binary.ld`.

And that are the contents of `binary.ld`:

```
ENTRY(_start);

SECTIONS
{
       _start = 0x0;  
}
```

Now you can execute your program: `./myfile`

Comment: If you're eventually going to use `ld` to make a normal static executable, you might as well just use an assembler if you're writing by hand.  You can use `.byte 0x90, 0x90, 0x90` to write three short-NOP instructions in GAS syntax, for example, and assemble + link that into the text section of an executable with `as foo.S` && `ld -o foo  foo.o`.  But sure, if you want to have a flat binary for some reason, yes this is a way to eventually link it into the text section of an executable.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there's something like exe2bin utility for the GNU tool set. I've used various versions of exe2bin with Microsoft tools, and the ARM toolkit has the ability to produce binaries, but I don't recall if it was directly from the linked output or something like exe2bin.

Comment: Good point - there is indeed something similar, you can use `objcopy´ to extract the opcodes from an object file