# Compile c struct to bin file

Tags: c

I have a C file:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
  uint32_t m1;
  uint16_t m2;
} TStruct;

TStruct s = {
  1,
  2
};
```

How to compile this file with gcc to produce little endian binary file?

```
0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02 0x00
```

Comment: compile it for an arch that uses little endian... and you also have to take care of alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Though, Little-Endian is the default for all standard configurations. A otherwise configured compiler toolkit can use this switch to fetch desired format.

```
    gcc file.c -mlittle-endian
```

There you go..

Answer (score 0):

I guess tying together the other answers. On a little endian machine (x86):

```
evaitl@evbb ~/se $ cat foo.c 
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
  uint32_t m1;
  uint16_t m2;
} TStruct;

TStruct s = {
  1,
  2
};
evaitl@evbb ~/se $ gcc -c foo.c 
evaitl@evbb ~/se $ objcopy -O binary foo.o  foo
evaitl@evbb ~/se $ hexdump -C foo
00000000  01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00                           |........|
00000008
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably

```
objcopy -O binary
```

is what you are looking for.See [[ this ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1647405/2878070) SO answer.