# Can I easily embed strings In a raw binary?

Tags: c, executable

I am aiming to create a raw x86 binary executable from C code. So far, I am able to create a raw binary file using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647359) (The rest of this question assumes you have read the other question). However, I want to use data like strings too. Since strings are stored in a different section of the object file, which isn't being copied over to the raw binary (when running this command: `objcopy -j .text -O binary main.o binfile`), I can't use strings though. How would I best embed static data like strings in my binary? (Ideally with a similar method to the one linked)

Comment: *Since strings are stored in a different section of the object file, which obviously isn't being copied over to the raw binary* - this is not true. You can also explicitly specify the sections to be copied as explained in the comments to the answer for the referenced question.

Comment: Does adding `-j .rodata` to your objcopy invocation work?

Comment: First examine the file to see where the literal strings are really stored. Then just add that section when copying.

Comment: @S.S.Anne that seems to overwrite part of the instructions. I assume because Both sections are copied to offset 0.

Comment: Please read `objcopy`'s documentation, or at least its on-line help, produced by option`--help`. There are options to changes addresses.