# Why did ld turn my 5 lines of library-less C into a 100MB binary?

Tags: c, gcc, x86, ld, osdev

I'm trying to develop some very low-level x86 code following [this](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/%7Eexr/lectures/opsys/10_11/lectures/os-dev.pdf) document. I wrote the following C program:

```
void main()
{
    char* video_memory = (char*) 0xb8000;
    *video_memory = 'X';
}
```

I compile and link it like so:

```
gcc -m32 -fno-pie -c main.c -o main.o
ld -m elf_i386 -o main.bin -Ttext 513 --oformat binary main.o
```

This produces a binary called `main.bin` which is **over a hundred megabytes**. I disassembled that binary and it's basically my code (ten or so lines), then a hundred meg of zeros, and then some kind of footer.

The extra bytes are all unnecessary, because I used `head` to snip off the ones that weren't my code and it still ran fine.

I'm using 32-bit flags because my test machine is an old 32-bit laptop, but you can get similar (but less extreme) behavior in 64-bit. This script:

```
gcc -fno-pie -c main.c -o main.o
ld -o main.bin -Ttext 513 --oformat binary main.o
```

produces a `main.bin` of over 4 MB. Again the pattern is the same: my code, 4 meg of zeros, and then a footer. A little bit of noise in between my code and the zeros. Here's the disassembled 4MB file:

```
       0:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
       4:   55                      push   %ebp
       5:   48                      dec    %eax
       6:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
       8:   48                      dec    %eax
       9:   c7 45 f8 00 80 0b 00    movl   $0xb8000,-0x8(%ebp)
      10:   48                      dec    %eax
      11:   8b 45 f8                mov    -0x8(%ebp),%eax
      14:   c6 00 58                movb   $0x58,(%eax)
      17:   90                      nop
      18:   5d                      pop    %ebp
      19:   c3                      ret    
    ...
     aea:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
     aec:   00 14 00                add    %dl,(%eax,%eax,1)
     aef:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
     af1:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
     af3:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
     af5:   01 7a 52                add    %edi,0x52(%edx)
     af8:   00 01                   add    %al,(%ecx)
     afa:   78 10                   js     0xb0c
     afc:   01 1b                   add    %ebx,(%ebx)
     afe:   0c 07                   or     $0x7,%al
     b00:   08 90 01 00 00 1c       or     %dl,0x1c000001(%eax)
     b06:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
     b08:   00 1c 00                add    %bl,(%eax,%eax,1)
     b0b:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
     b0d:   f3 f4                   repz hlt 
     b0f:   ff                      (bad)  
     b10:   ff 1a                   lcall  *(%edx)
     b12:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
     b14:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
     b16:   45                      inc    %ebp
     b17:   0e                      push   %cs
     b18:   10 86 02 43 0d 06       adc    %al,0x60d4302(%esi)
     b1e:   51                      push   %ecx
     b1f:   0c 07                   or     $0x7,%al
     b21:   08 00                   or     %al,(%eax)
    ...
  3ffaeb:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
  3ffaed:   04 00                   add    $0x0,%al
  3ffaef:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
  3ffaf1:   10 00                   adc    %al,(%eax)
  3ffaf3:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
  3ffaf5:   05 00 00 00 47          add    $0x47000000,%eax
  3ffafa:   4e                      dec    %esi
  3ffafb:   55                      push   %ebp
  3ffafc:   00 02                   add    %al,(%edx)
  3ffafe:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
  3ffb00:   c0 04 00 00             rolb   $0x0,(%eax,%eax,1)
  3ffb04:   00 03                   add    %al,(%ebx)
  3ffb06:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
  3ffb08:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
  3ffb0a:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
    ...
```

The giant binary files *works*, but it's ugly and I'd like to understand what's going on.

I'm doing the compilation/linking on Ubuntu 20.20 on a 64-bit machine. Tool versions:

```
gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34
```

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: @NateEldredge Added that to the end of the question.

Comment: If you link to elf instead (remove `--oformat binary`) and run `objdump -h` you see there is a section `.note.gnu.property` which is located at address `0x080480f4` which is your 130 MB.  In binary format the only way to accomplish that is to write all the zeros in between.  Why the section has that address, or whether it ought to be present at all, I don't know.

Comment: Generally speaking I suspect you are going to have to do something more involved to get gcc to generate a flat binary, e.g. writing your own linker script.  I don't know what it ought to consist of, though.

Comment: @NateEldredge: yes, writing your own linker script is standard for kernels, especially flat binaries.  You can simply omit mention of other sections and they won't be included.  (You do have to make sure you include all sections where GCC puts code/data, though.)  I'm not an expert in linker scripts, but I've definitely seen simple examples in answers to other SO questions, probably easy to find with google for something like `site:stackoverflow.com linker script flat binary`

Comment: For now I'm using `objcopy` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8207821/815612). I'll be sure to leave an answer if I get to the bottom of this some day.

Comment: `void main()` is only valid in free-standing environments, so I guess you need the [`-ffreestanding` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17692428/995714)

Comment: When I did the same thing: https://github.com/acmiitr/KSOS/blob/fb8c4b187ca3113c94c9845a51511c7a58aa2d1a/Makefile, I used `gcc -ffreestanding -c -fno-pie -m32` and `ld -m elf_i386 -Ttext 0x1000 --oformat binary`. However, right now I use a custom linker script, and it's just much better.

Comment: You should really consider using a cross compiler. The address `0x0804????` would be a typical Linux address for 32-bit code. That address is part of the linker script used by your GCC. You can create your own linker script (what many people do) or you will have to exclude the `.note.gnu.property` section from your binary. You should compile with `-ffreestanding` and I recommend `-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables` . Rather than having LD output binary, I recommend outputting as ELF and then use OBJCOPY to convert the file to flat binary and have it remove the unneeded section.

Comment: Try `gcc -ffreestanding -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -m32 -fno-pie -c main.c -o main.o` `ld -nostartfiles -m elf_i386 -o main.elf -Ttext 513 main.o` `objcopy -O binary main.elf main.bin --remove-section .note.gnu.property` . On a side note `-Ttext 513` is a rather peculiar VMA to use. I'd be curious how you chose it?

Comment: @PeterCordes : In a linker script you have to explicitly DISCARD sections. Any section that is not explicitly mentioned in the linker script will still be processed, and there are rules as to how they are placed in the resulting file.

Comment: @MichaelPetch The 513 was a mistake. My idea was that since the code would be starting at offset 513 on the USB stick (the boot sector is 512 bytes), I should use that, but of course in RAM the bootsector starts at 0x7c0 so in fact it should be 0x9c1 since I just decided to load the second sector of the USB stick in RAM.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Could you explain what you mean by a cross-compiler? GCC with the packages I installed can cross-compile, does that not make "a cross-compiler"?

Comment: @JackM: 0x7c00 + 512 = 0x7e00, not ...1.  The boot sector starts at offset `...0`, not `...1`, and you left out a 0 in the offset relative to segment base=0.  Therefore 513 leaves a gap of 1 byte.  (Or if you're talking about segment bases, 0x7c0+513 leaves a gap of `513*16 - 512` bytes because you forgot to scale down for the size of a paragraph (16 bytes))

Comment: I was referring to a generic ELF GCC Cross Compiler that isn't tied to your native tool chain. More information on them can be found on the OSDev Wiki: https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler

Comment: Does your bootloader/second stage put the processor into 32-bit protected mode before trying to execute this code? Where in memory did you load the kernel?

Comment: @MichaelPetch The bootloader (since I made a couple of changes after reading these comments) loads the compiled C code at offset `0x7c00 + 0x200`, *then* enters protected mode, and then jumps to the C code.

Comment: If that is what you have done then you'd have to use `-Ttext 0x7e00`

Comment: @MichaelPetch Indeed - but in the meantime I've switched to `objcopy` anyway so right now it's a moot point. The code works right now anyway because I got lucky this time and the compiler compiled my loops and ifs as IP relative jumps.